# LVM_GETITEM confusion

Tags: c, listview, winapi

The [`LVM_GETITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message documentation says:

[image]

I'm not sure I understand what does the highlighted text means, does it mean that the buffer that I set to the `pszText` member could not be used, but rather the `pszText` member could map to a string that is placed elsewhere in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure I understand what does the highlighted text means, does it mean that the buffer that I set to the pszText member could not be used, but rather the pszText member could map to a string that is placed elsewhere in memory?

Yes, that is exactly what it means.